# Java Web Start Offline mode not possible with JRE 8u171

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, offline-mode

Does anyone still uses Java Web Start? Well I certanly have to.

I have an application that needs to run in online and offline mode. Online for getting updates, but the actual use case is offline.

Up to jre8u161 that worked fine. But with the current Updates 171 and 172 the application won't start in offline mode.

If I force it to offline mode with the Java Cache Viewer I get the exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Ressource kann nicht heruntergeladen werden. System ist offline. (Resource can not be downloaded. System is offline.)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.checkUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.isUpdateAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.model.ResourceProvider.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I start it with `javaws -offline <jnlp-file>` I get the message "Anwedung im Offlinebetrieb nicht verfügbar" (Application in offline mode not available).

I created a minimal application with this jnlp-file:

```
<jnlp spec="7.0" codebase="<URL>" href="<jnlp-file>"
  <information>
    <title>Base Test</title>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <jar href="<jar-file>"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="test.BaseTest"/>
</jnlp>
```

But this also won't start in offline mode.

What else can I do?

Comment: We just started getting reports of this issue with our users with update 171.  I'm guessing that this was broken by Java with the latest update somehow.  They've broke it before in the past.  It's been awhile, but this appears to be the case now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at least now I know I'm not alone.

Comment: "What else can I do?" - For a start, raise a bug report with sufficient detail that the Java team can reproduce the problem.  Write them an MCVE!

Comment: "Does anyone still uses Java Web Start? Well I certainly have to." - You will need to find another way soon ... 'cos webstart is going away, unless you / your customers are prepared to pay for an Oracle support contract.   You could treat this incident as the proverbial straw that breaks the camel's back .....

Answer (score 2):

This is a know bug of JDK 8 171 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8203272

This is fixed in later version of JAVA (able to launch jnlp in offline mode with java 10 )

There is no way to launch JNLP in off line mode with 8-171 java update.

FOR DESKTOP SHORTCUT LAUNCH
One of the work around would be(It is just a hack)
1. create 2 different jnlp one for java 8-171 and another for launch jnlp in offline mode for other java versions.

2. Create a launcher jnlp app which detect version of java on client local and launch respective jnlp.

(I am current working on it will update code when done)

USE this config in JNLP

JAVA 8 171

```
          <offline-allowed/>
           <shortcut>
            <desktop/>
           </shortcut>
```

JAVA OTHER version

```
          `<offline-allowed/>
           <shortcut online="false">
             <desktop/>
           </shortcut>`
```